# python 3.8.2 global_argparse

Tags: python, argparse, python-3.8

I am trying to run a python script that was originally run in Linux/CentOS in Windows7. So, I installed python 3.8.2 and several dependencies such as numpy, pandas, dateutil, six and pytz in windows 7. But now I am getting an error in the following section of the code

```
from tools import global_argparse as argparse
```

It says that "No module named 'tools' ". I haven't been able to find this "global_argparse" library for windows 7. Is there a dependency I am missing? Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Do you have access to the machine that the script used to run on?  If so you can do `import tools; print(tools.__file__)` on that box to see where it is coming from.  It may be a custom module that someone wrote as opposed to an official package.  (Based on the name, I would expect it to be something like `import argparse; global_argparse = argparse; argparse = # my own custom argparse`.)

Comment: Yes, you re correct. It's a vendor specific library.